# Setting input control focus without javascript

Tags: html

Is there a way to set the focus in a specific HTML input (a textarea control, actually), without using Javascript?

EDIT: Is possible in HTML5 but the question is about HTML < 5

Comment: Apparently my 2009 question is a duplicate of a 2010 question...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope. Sadly JavaScript is required, because it's dynamically modifying the browser on the client-side (what JavaScript was made for).

Comment: I see people are still viewing this post; this is slightly incorrect with HTML5. In HTML5-compliant browsers, you can add `<input autofocus />` to your tag to auto-focus the element when the page loads without javascript. Check http://wufoo.com/html5/attributes/02-autofocus.html for details.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [autofocus](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control) in HTML5 documents, but it has little support at present ([see chart](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#autofocus)).

Comment: Of course, it's very easy to polyfill `autofocus` (jQuery used for brevity): `$(function () {$('[autofocus]').first().focus()});`

Comment: [Nowadays broswer support](http://caniuse.com/#search=autofocus).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any, other than tabbing to the field or clicking within it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how and when you want to set the focus on this textarea. "tabindex" might help you.