# Set default focused element/input

Tags: html, css

I know I can set an element to be focused on document load using JS/jQuery:

```
$('#myInput').focus();
```

My question is if it's possible to do it using CSS only, no script.

Comment: perhaps the HTML5 input `autofocus` attribute?

Comment: @RoxDorentus +1, thanks. the only exception with this attribute is IE, obviously.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting input control focus without javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983013/setting-input-control-focus-without-javascript)

Comment: @j08691, they're different questions. This one's asking about CSS, the other one's asking about not using JavaScript.

Comment: @zzzzBov - yes however if you read the answers and comments you'll see that the answer is that it's can't be done without JavaScript unless you use HTML5. In other words, it can't be done in CSS.

Comment: @j08691, different questions can have the same answer. That doesn't make the question any less different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to set focus in CSS. It’s not the kind of things CSS is designed for, as it is a behavior issue.

As noted in a comment, in HTML you can set initial focus using the `autofocus` attribute.